# Get array values and put in while

Tags: php

I get some values from DB and put results on array

GET from users

```
$foo = array();
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT item_audit_id FROM mod_users_files");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
$foo['item_audit_id'] = $row;
```

When I print `print_r($foo);` i get correct values, like

```
Array ( [item_audit_id] => Array ( [item_audit_id] => 13 ) ) 

Array ( [item_audit_id] => Array ( [item_audit_id] => 1 ) )
```

Now, i have another while, and 'm like to check if item_audit_id exist and show information to user:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) {
        $class_item_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"class_item_id");
        $class_item_descrption = mysql_result($result,$i,"class_item_description");
        ?>
        <tr class="grade">
            <td><?php echo $class_item_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $class_item_description; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                if (in_array($class_item_id, $foo)) { 
                    echo "<p style='color:green'>Exist</p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p style='color:red'>Missing</p>";   
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>                    
</tbody>
```

If I declare array in this way:

```
$foo = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
```

results are correct, on while below i cant get any results.

Where do I wrong?

Thanks all for help;

Comment: You have forgotten the i in $class_item_descrption

Comment: Where does `$result` come from? And where is `$num` defined?

Comment: I think it's better with PDO instead of mysql_*. Learn today what still works tomorrow. Not learn today what worked yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning this variable over and over

```
$foo['item_audit_id'] = $row;
```

You probably want

```
$foo[] = $row['item_audit_id'];
```